# Jupyter notebook split output on 2 columns

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, output, data-science, ipython

Often I compare two models using different metrics in the notebook. It would be pretty good if I can just split cell output into 2 columns, fill the first column, then fill the second column.

Now I am calling a function that prints all metrics one by one

```
check_metrics(model_path)
check_metrics(producion_model_pathes[label])
```

The output of check metrics looks like [output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoEjX.png)

Is it possible to split the output into 2 columns, then set as default output the first column, then before calling the second function set the second column as default output? So the output must be looks like the 2 pictures (like above) stacked vertically

Comment: Maybe some of the suggestions and ideas discussed in [Feature Request-Two column mode](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2791) may help you? If you really just prefer an alternate view for only this example you could, use scrapbook and collect the output and display it as you want in markdown, see [here](https://github.com/nteract/scrapbook#scraps_report-displays-a-report-about-collected-scraps) that you open in another side window with JupyterLab? How general or custom do you need this. Use `%% capture` cell magic and compositing something you display in another cell may suffice?

Comment: JupyterLab has a feature that may be helpful here. You can right-click on any output and select 'Create New View for Output'. Arrange the pane that comes up any way you want by clicking on the tab & dragging it around. And you can even go back & open another view from the same output and place that pane.  You may want to check out [ipylab](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab) which allows for 'Control JupyterLab from Python notebooks', especially see 'SplitPanel' demo in `widgets.ipynb` in the launch binder demo. Plus see [sidecar](https://twitter.com/SylvainCorlay/status/1029495925473980416).

Answer (score 7):

Just use the `ipywidgets.widgets` to create an output widget and set any thing with you want inside:

```
output1 = widgets.Output()
with output1:
    display(check_metrics(model_path))
output2 = widgets.Output()
with output2:
    display(check_metrics(model_path))

two_columns = widgets.HBox([output1, output2])
display(two_columns)
```