# How to plot figures side by side in custom function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a few plots using Matplotlib and partial_dependence that I use the below code to generate:

```
def plot_pdp(model, X, feature, target=False, return_pd=False, y_pct=True, figsize=(10,9), norm_hist=True, dec=.5):
    # Get partial dependence
    pardep = partial_dependence(model, X, [feature])
    
    # Get min & max values
    xmin = pardep[1][0].min()
    xmax = pardep[1][0].max()
    ymin = pardep[0][0].min()
    ymax = pardep[0][0].max()
    
    # Create figure
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    ax1.grid(alpha=.5, linewidth=1)
    
    # Plot partial dependence
    color = 'tab:blue'
    ax1.plot(pardep[1][0], pardep[0][0], color=color)
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
    ax1.set_xlabel(feature, fontsize=14)
    
    tar_ylabel = ': {}'.format(target) if target else ''
    ax1.set_ylabel('Partial Dependence{}'.format(tar_ylabel), color=color, fontsize=14)
    
    tar_title = target if target else 'Target Variable'
    ax1.set_title('Relationship Between {} and {}'.format(feature, tar_title), fontsize=16)
    
    if y_pct and ymin>=0 and ymax<=1:
        # Display yticks on ax1 as percentages
        fig.canvas.draw()
        labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax1.get_yticklabels()]
        labels = [int(np.float(label)*100) for label in labels]
        labels = ['{}%'.format(label) for label in labels]
        ax1.set_yticklabels(labels)
    
    # Plot line for decision boundary
    #ax1.hlines(dec, xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, color='black', linewidth=2, linestyle='--', label='Decision Boundary')
    #ax1.legend()

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    color = 'tab:red'
    ax2.hist(X[feature], bins=80, range=(xmin, xmax), alpha=.25, color=color, density=norm_hist)
    ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
    ax2.set_ylabel('Distribution', color=color, fontsize=14)
    
    if y_pct and norm_hist:
        # Display yticks on ax2 as percentages
        fig.canvas.draw()
        labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax2.get_yticklabels()]
        labels = [int(np.float(label)*100) for label in labels]
        labels = ['{}%'.format(label) for label in labels]
        ax2.set_yticklabels(labels)

    plt.show()
    
    if return_pd:
        return pardep
```

Then I can get a plot for each column using :

```
for i in X.columns:
    plot_pdp(model, X, i, target='nof_visit')
```

In a Jupyter notebook the plots are shown one below another. How can I change it so that it is shown side by side?

Edit: When I try subplots on this line `'fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, len(X.columns) ,figsize=figsize)'`, I get the below error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [174], in <cell line: 71>()
     69         return pardep
     71 for i in X.columns:
---> 72     plot_pdp(model, X, i, target='nof_visit')

Input In [174], in plot_pdp(model, X, feature, target, return_pd, y_pct, figsize, norm_hist, dec)
     11     # Create figure
     12     fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, len(X.columns) ,figsize=figsize)
---> 13     ax1.grid(alpha=.5, linewidth=1)
     15 #     SMALL_SIZE = 20
     16 #     MEDIUM_SIZE = 40
     17 #     BIGGER_SIZE = 40
   (...)
     27     
     28     # Plot partial dependence
     29     color = 'tab:blue'

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

Comment: how about `axs = subplots(nrows=..., ncols=...)` to create places for plots, and later use every `ax` to plot in different place. [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

Comment: I have few options with example code for a different kind of plot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72722172/8508004). If you are just looking to view you can make new output for every output in JupyterLab and arrange the windows side by side. [sidecar](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-sidecar) by default creates new tabs for the one sidecar window as you add more sidecars; I don't know if you can generate multiple views using it with some options that it has built in. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71079373/8508004) for related discussion.

Comment: @furas when I try subplots on this line 'fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, len(X.columns) ,figsize=figsize)', i get the error, ''AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'grid'".

Comment: @Wayne I have added an edit. I get an error when trying subplots with n_row, n_cols

Comment: I cannot tell from what you've shared, what `X` is? From the edited error, it seems it is an array so you need to cast it to something `len()` or subplots can use, maybe? Need a single integer as a result, I think.

Comment: X is a dataframe. len(X.columns) just outputs an integer. Can't get the rest of the code to work unfortunately

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: subplots should give you list with many `ax` and you may have to run `.grid()` on every `ax` separately. `fig, many_axs = subplots(...)` and `for ax in many_axs: ax.grid(...)`

Comment: @furas I have updated the question with full error. Could you explain how to implement that?